# Trouble installing Yeoman Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: windows, node.js, npm, nodes

```
npm ERR! `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED`
npm ERR!     `at errnoException (net.js:904:11)`
npm ERR!     `at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:895:19)`
npm ERR!  `{ [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]`
npm ERR!   `code: 'ECONNREFUSED',`
npm ERR!   `errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',`
npm ERR!   `syscall: 'connect' }`
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

Whenever I run `npm install -g yo`, I get the error listed above.  I'm unsure what to do next.

Comment: Are you behind any firewall/proxy ?

Comment: I don't have any idea. Doing first time. What do you think might be the possiblity ?

Comment: Do we required to set any proxy or else before start ?

Comment: This could easyly be a problem related to: Proxy, Firewall, DNS... You could easyly add Googles DNS 8.8.8.8 to resolv.conf and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks ! everyone for their reply. Issue fixed. It required me to set proxy of working network like http://proxy.<companyname>.com:<port>

Answer (score 0):

Just had to set

npm config set proxy http://usr:pwd@proxyname:port

npm config set https-proxy http://usr:pwd@proxyname:port